# gvim - jumplist to functions within a file

Tags: vim

I'm using VIM to work with Powershell files. How do I make gvim:

- show full list of strings that match some regex? (either in new buffer or in command window)
- go to a line selected in the found list?

Answer (score 2):

The following command will get you all the matching lines into the command window.

```
:vimgrep /INSERT_EXPRESSION_HERE/ % | cw
```

You can then use normal vim navigation to find the line inside the command window, and hit `Enter` to jump to that line in the file. To return to the list again, you can use the normal vim Window movement commands `C-w,j` in normal mode.

Answer (score 1):

For a non-persistent list of search results, you can use the built-in `:ilist` command to list and `:ijump` to jump. My [FindOccurrence plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4922) has extended mappings (`[/` to query for a pattern, list all occurrences, and query for a number to jump to, and `[N` which uses the current search pattern). Here's a little demo:

### [image]

To persist the list of search results, `:vimgrep` with the *quickfix list* can be used (as shown in @merlin2011's answer). My [GrepHere plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4191) makes this even easier. Again, a short demo:
[image]

Comment: a bit OT, but... how did you do these demos ?

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira: That's [Cropper](http://cropper.codeplex.com/), .NET-based and Open Source, with the Animated Gif output plugin.